# Newton's laws and the maximum speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, speed-of-light

According to Newton's second law of motion : $F = ma$

In an certain occasion, we exert 2 forces (the magnitudes of the forces are the same) on 2 different objects, Object A and Object B, in the same direction (let's assume that the beginning velocity of the two objects is 0). The duration time of the force that we exerted on object A was much longer than the duration time of the force that we exerted on object B.

1. Will eventually the two objects will have the same velocity even though the duration time of the forces is different? After all, the maximum speed they could possibly move at is the speed of the light. What will happen in the next time unit (e.g. seconds) after the objects will reach the maximum speed? Will the two objects keep accelerating or will they move at the same velocity (the maximum speed in nature)?

*During the time where both forces are applied, both of the objects were able to reach a speed which is near to the speed of light.

2. What brought the scientists to the assumption that a maximum speed exists?
   On what is such assumption based?

Comment: what's your approach?

Comment: @Christian ,In a certain manner , the special relativity and Newton's laws of motions contradict each other. My question is about occasion which involve both. If you don't know anything about it , please do not comment.

Comment: You are misunderstanding Newton's laws. They are not in contradiction to special relativity. Why do you believe they are contradictory?

Comment: According to Newton's laws of motion , there is no such thing maximum velocity. As long as i exert a certain force on an object , it's velocity will keep growing.

Comment: Newton's Laws say nothing directly about maximum velocity, but they certainly *don't* imply there is "no such thing". You don't understand Newton's Laws or special relativity. The velocity will not grow linearly. It asymptotically approaches a maximum.

Comment: @BillN: in Newtonian mechanics if you apply a constant force, the velocity most certainly will increase forever.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Please, define what you mean by Newtonian mechanics. Do you mean classical mechanics where p=mv rather than $\gamma m v$?

Comment: @BillN: Sure.  Mechanics that obeys Newton's laws.  Special relativity in the limit $c\rightarrow \infty$.  Whatever.  I feel that you're being purposefully facetious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **1. Will eventually the two objects will have the same velocity**

**Newton**

No, in the Newtonian model the longer you apply a force to an object the faster it travels (assuming no other forces apply, in an atmosphere for example, there might be a terminal velocity regardless of the continuing application of force).

However Newton's laws are only valid for $v \ll c$

**SR**

Not in any measurable time. As $v$ increases closer to $c$ the acceleration due to the constant force will be less and less. $v$ will only approach $c$ as time approaches infinity.

> **What will happen in the next time unit**

There is no next time unit after $t = \infty$

> **2. What brought the scientists to the assumption that a maximum speed exists?**

It is more an observation (or a prediction from the application of a mathematical model based on observations). It isn't really an assumption.

> **On what based such <strike>assumption?</strike> [assertion]**

As I understand it, it all follows from the observation that the speed of light is a constant, different observers, moving inertially relative to one another, all record the same speed. Everything follows mathematically from that.

> **the special relativity and Newton's laws of motions contradict each other**

They don't *contradict* one another. If you take SR equations of motion and use the constraint $v \ll c$ you arrive at Newton's equations of motion. This view may be controversial - e.g. see [THE NEWTONIAN LIMIT OF RELATIVITY THEORY AND THE
RATIONALITY OF THEORY CHANGE](http://www.ucm.es/data/cont/docs/481-2013-10-14-TheNewtonianLimit.pdf)

Both Newton's equations of motion and those of SR produce the same results for macroscopic velocities typically experienced directly by humans. At least, the differences are insignificant, too small to measure conventionally.

Comment: The forces applied forever. The other guy that answered didn't understand it too. It is obvious that when the forces will cease to apply there will no acceleration. My question regards occasion where the objects keep accelerating until their velocity will reach it's maximum.

Comment: @Michael: Ah OK, answer updated.

Comment: @Michael: the problem is that there is no point where the "velocity reaches its maximum".  It's like asking how long you'll have to wait for $1 - e^{-t}$ to reach its maximum.

Answer (score 0):

$F=ma$ is a classical approximation to a more complete expression $\vec{F}=\dfrac{d\vec{p}}{dt},$  so it doesn't work well at speeds about approximately 0.1c (c is speed of photons).

That means we find the change in momentum, $$\Delta\vec{p}=\int_{t1}^{t2}\vec{F}dt.$$ To continue the simplified version you started, let the force be constant. That means that $$\Delta\vec{p}=\vec{F}(t_2-t_1).$$

In your problem, both particles start with $\vec{p}=0,$ and $t_1=0.$ Therefore, $\vec{p}_A=\vec{F}t_A$ and $\vec{p}_B=\vec{F}t_B.$ Because the forces are identical and $t_A > t_B$, then $p_A>p_B$ for all $t>0$. They never reach speed $c$. You also state that there is a time for each object at which the force ends. When this happens, the momentum (and velocity) of each will remain constant.

In classical language, when the forces stop, the accelerations will stop and the velocities will remain constant. So different times in your problem guarantee different final velocities.

The existence of a maximum speed limit is a consequence of the rotation of spacetime coordinates.  It so happens that this limit is the same as the speed of photons.  The basis for the way the rotation works is found in Einstein's postulates of special relativity.  It's actually the rotation of Minkowski space.

Comment: In my question the forces are exerted forever. Based on the fact that the highest speed in nature is the speed of light , I inferred that every object has a maximum velocity so at some point , both of the objects will reach the maximum speed which is the same.

Comment: You said " The duration time of the force that we exerted on object A was much longer than the duration time of the force that we exerted on object B." This means that at least the time on object B is shorter than on object A, which means the impulse on B is always smaller, thus A will always have more momentum. And you never said "forever" before your previous comment. If the momentum of B is always smaller, the speed of B is always smaller.

Comment: In t = 0 , the two objects are located in the same position (for instance (0,0,0)) . In t = 5[s] for instance , force A applies on object A. In t = 10[s] , force B applies on object B. both of forces (A and B) applies for infinite time. I just wanted to emphasize the point that there are two objects with different beginning velocities  and they are reaching the maximum velocity.

Comment: Never said anything in my post about forces being cease to apply. If there is difference between duration time , you could understand that if force B applies for infinite time , force A will applies for even more.

Comment: @Michael - You cannot apply a force for more than infinite time.

Comment: There is no maximum speed for massive particles. You can always go a little bit faster (but never reach the speed of light).